# Define a binary composition ( operation ) $\star$ such that $\langle G,\star\rangle$ is a group with $a$ as its identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G $ be any non identity element i.e. $a\neq e$. Define a binary composition ( operation ) $\star$ such that $\langle G,\star \rangle$ is a group with $a$ as its identity.

I am new to the class of the Abstract Algebra and this was a question which was asked to solved on the third day. I don't think I understood the concept and question well enough to solve the problem.

Kindly help with the concepts and provide good explanation to the steps to reduce further confusion. Moreover, suggestions regarding a good book to read will be also helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: What I think is that the question missed a very crucial information that, it should be G be a group under _________ operation. Only then it will be possible to solve. Correct me if I am wrong !!

Comment: @Amir I didn't get your hint. Could you be a little more specific, why  $\star : {G} \times {G}\mapsto {G}$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $g*h = ga^{-1}h$, where the product on the right uses the original group structure.

Comment: How it is that that on the right uses the original group structure. Could you be a little more specific, Please !! I am having problem understanding.

Comment: That is not a hint, but the solution. I think it would be better to say how one gets to this definition. @1729, say $(G, \cdot)$ is a group, then you have nothing more then the group operation $\cdot : G \times G \to G$, and multiplication with some group element $\cdot g : G \to G$ to define your new operation. Then note that $e \star a = e$ and you get to Alex' definition.

Comment: @MoritzDoll It's not a complete solution in the sense that one has to check that this does define a group structure, and that it satisfies the required property.

Comment: @MoritzDoll: In the question when it says ' Let G be a group and 'a' belongs to 'G' be any non identity element ' Does it mean that G is a group under multiplication, where a is not the identity element. If so, how to know about that ??

Comment: @AlexProvost but that is almost trivial.

Comment: @1729 if you have an abstract group $(G, \cdot)$ given, you call the group operation "multiplication", but it can be anything, really (for example take the real numbers and the usual addition). There are plenty of abstract algebra books, for example the one by Serge Lang.

Comment: @MoritzDoll but $(G, \cdot)$ was not given.

Comment: @1729 The sentence "Let $G$ be a group" implies that $G$ is a set endowed with a binary operation satisfying the group properties.

Comment: @MoritzDoll: $\cdot : G \times G \to G$ Here 'G X G' means G multiplied to G or an ordered pair ? I am getting confused with the symbols and context.

Comment: It was, it was only not written down properly. If you say "Let $G$ be a group" you mean that there is a group operation, but you didn't name it.

Comment: Okay I get "implies that G is a set endowed with a binary operation satisfying the group properties." but when it means 'binary operation' it doesnot mean that it should be **multiplication**

Comment: @1729 The group operation is usually referred to as "multiplication" by default.